# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: positioning

Tags: 14.04, apt, qt5, qmake, qt4

I have error `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: positioning`  when I'm trying to build QT5 dependent project with `qmake`, I suspect that problem can be in old QT4 installation that was installed before.

```
qmake -version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

So my questions are:

1.How to resolve this error?

2.How to completelly remove Qt4 (and maybe reinstall QT5?)?

**Update:**

```
which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake

ls -l /usr/bin/qmake
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 апр.   4  2016 /usr/bin/qmake -> qtchooser

dpkg -l|grep qt5|grep qmake
ii  qt5-qmake:amd64                                       5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3                              amd64        Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool

qt5-qmake
lots of output like /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake

qtchooser -list-versions
4
5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5

qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

After I set `export QT_SELECT=qt5`:

```
qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="qt5"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Also I have tried:

```
qtchooser -run-tool=qmake -qt=qt5 ../src
```

But I still have same error.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the development files for QT5 positioning module using this command:

```
sudo apt install qtpositioning5-dev
```

Also make sure your system defaults to QT5 instead of QT4:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to use qmake from Qt Version 5. This depends on you PATH Variable if you type in "qmake" in your Terminal.

The following steps may help you as an solution:

```
1. check the path of qmake for Qt Version 5
   command: dpkg -l|grep qt5|grep qmake
   if you found the right name, see the details of the installed path:
   command: dpkg -L 
2. set the path to qmake of Qt 5 in the right order
   command: export PATH=:$PATH
3. use qtchooser to switch between version of Qt development
   command: qtchooser -list-versions
   command: qtchooser -print-env
   command: qtchooser -qt=version
   have a look to "man qtchooser" !
```

Go to your source and run "qmake" again. You don't need to uninstall Qt4. You can more then one development Versions on your system.

Comment: Udpdated question.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the Error

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: positioning
```

make sure you have added

```
QT += positioning
```

to your .pro file. Please have a look also to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtpositioning-module.html form more configuration to use Qt Positioning C++ Classes